# IIS - Error: Unrecognized Attribute "configBuilders"

Tags: sql-server, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp-net-config-builders

[image: Error Message]

I've been trying to get an ASP.NET API setup, but I keep getting this error on the IIS Server when trying to check the Connection Strings. The project is a straight up new ASP.NET API Project with only 2 added variables to the registration table.

My Connection String (web.config):

```
<configBuilders>
<builders>
<add name="Secrets" userSecretsId="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.UserSecretsConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.UserSecrets, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxx" />
</builders>
</configBuilders>

<connectionStrings configBuilders="Secrets">
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=myAPIApp;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxx" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: have you declared a configBuilders section under <configSections>? Take a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/config-builder

Comment: I believe I have:
<configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" requirePermission="false" />
<section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>

Answer (score -1):

After installed the below `Nuget` package,
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Environment/
We should register `configbuilder` firstly before using a custom configuration builder.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection,
             System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
             PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
```

Please refer to my configuration of obtaining the `ServiceID` from `System Environment Variables` preferentially.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection,
             System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
             PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <configBuilders>
    <builders>
      <add name="Secrets" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.EnvironmentConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Environment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </builders>
  </configBuilders>

  <appSettings configBuilders="Secrets">
    <add key="ServiceID" value="ServiceID value from web.config" />
    <add key="ServiceKey" value="Spotify" />
  </appSettings>

  <connectionStrings configBuilders="Secrets">
    <add name="default" connectionString="Data Source=web.config/mydb.db" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

`ServiceID/ServiceKey` will be obtained the value from System Environment Variables if it sets.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: All of that is in the project, yes.
I'm starting to believe it's an issue with the IIS Server.

Comment: This seems to be an IIS issue.